# form.is_valid() returns false on Login Page

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have been trying to create a login takes in registered users and authenticate them into the website. For some reason, it when executing it form.is_valid() always returns false even though I am pointing it to the right form in. The following is my views.py file

```
from django.views import generic
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.views.generic import View
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .registrationform import UserForm
from .loginform import UserLoginForm
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class IndexView(View):
    form_class = UserLoginForm
    template_name = 'login/login_form.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(None)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        print(form.is_valid())
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None and user.is_active():
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('sports:index')
            else:
                return redirect('login:login')
        else:
            return HttpResponse(request, status=500)

class CreateUser(View):
    form_class = UserForm
    template_name = 'login/registration_form.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(None)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        print(form.is_valid())
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            pass1 = form.cleaned_data['password']
            pass2 = form.cleaned_data['repeatpassword']
            if pass1 != pass2:
                messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, 'Passwords do not match')
                return redirect('login:register')
            else:
                user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, email=email, password=pass1)
                user.save()
                return redirect('login:login')
            return HttpResponse(request, status=200)
        else:
            return HttpResponse(request, status=500)
```

This is my urls.py page

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth.views import login

app_name = 'login'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name="login"),
    path('register', views.CreateUser.as_view(), name='register')
]
```

This is my login_forms.html page

```
  <form class="" action="{% url 'login:login' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
{% csrf_token %}
{% for field in form %}
  <label>{{ field.label_tag }}</label>
  <div>{{ field }}</div>
{% endfor %}
<button type="submit" name="register">Register</button>
```

Create Account {% endblock %}

This is my registration_form.html

```
{% extends 'sports/base.html' %}
{% block body %}
  <title>{% block title %} Register {% endblock %}</title>
  <h1>Create Account</h1>

  <form class="" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
      <label>{{ field.label_tag }}</label>
      <div>{{ field }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit" name="register">Register</button>
  </form>
  {% if messages %}
    {% for message in messages %}
      <p>{{ message }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

What I do not understand is that I pretty much copied the code for registering the user for logging in the user but it seems to be returning false even though I am pointing it to the correct template_name.

The IndexView class is supposed to log in the users and is linked to the login_form.html and the CreateUser class is used to register users and is linked to the registration_form.html.

I am new to learning Django and any help would be gladly appreciated.

Comment: Check `form.errors` field for the details.

Comment: in your post method change form = self.form_class(self.request.POST). You have to call self.request.POST

Comment: Remove `enctype="multipart/form-data"` and one extra `{% csrf_token %}` from login_forms.html